# How to change the view at runtime

Tags: android

I currently using a layout named "ax", 
Now I have to switch to full screen view and for some time with some button on it which is there in linear layout , on click of one of the view I want to come back to normal view ("ax"), 
How can I do that ?
if i do  `setContentView(ax);`  then it redraws the view , which is not permitted.

Comment: Why is redrawing the view "not permitted"?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a seperate activity for the full screen view. This will be shown on top of the ax view, which will remain untouched.

Comment: I have some restriction for creating activity , so could not create it